# NHibernate Linq ToFuture and Max

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I want the following two queries to be executed in single round trip to database so I'm using ToFutureValue.

```
var query = AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.User == user);

var singinCount = query
    .Where(x => x.ActionDate >= from && x.ActionDate <= to)
    .ToFutureValue(q => q.Count());

var lastSignin = query
    .Where(x => x.ActionName.ToLower() == Actions.Signin))
    .ToFutureValue(q => q.Max(x => x.ActionDate));
```

The problem is that Count and Max returns result but not IQueryable. I have found the following extension that enables me to pass Count to ToFutureValue:

```
public static IFutureValue<TResult> ToFutureValue<TSource, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<IQueryable<TSource>, TResult>> selector)
        where TResult : struct
    {
        var provider = (INhQueryProvider)source.Provider;
        var method = ((MethodCallExpression)selector.Body).Method;
        var expression = Expression.Call((Expression)null, method, source.Expression);

        return (IFutureValue<TResult>)provider.ExecuteFuture(expression);
    }
```

Now I need to adopt that extension for Max because I have to pass arguments to Max (.ToFutureValue(q => q.Max(x => x.ActionDate))). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a workaround

```
var lastSignin = query
    .Where(x => x.ActionName.ToLower() == Actions.Signin))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ActionDate)
    .Take(1)
    .ToFutureValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is appropriate patch in GitHub pull request
[#120](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/120)

And here is jira bug [NH-3184](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3184)

the following is code from pull #120 that works:

```
public static IFutureValue<TResult> ToFutureValue<T, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, TResult>> selector)
{
    var nhQueryable = query as QueryableBase<T>;    
    if (nhQueryable == null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Query needs to be of type QueryableBase<T>");
    }


    var provider = (INhQueryProvider) query.Provider;
    var expression = ReplacingExpressionTreeVisitor.Replace(
            selector.Parameters.Single(),
            query.Expression,
            selector.Body);

    return (IFutureValue<TResult>) provider.ExecuteFuture(expression);
}
```